# Koa Endpoint always return 404

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, async-await, koa

I've been running in a problem where I believe a call is returning too early and makes my response always a 404 - Not Found message. The entry is made in the database, so it's returning early from what I can tell. I think I've awaited the correct parts, but clearly that is not the case. I've also tried awaiting on the db.AddUser as well, with no luck there.

**Endpoint**

```
//Post signup
public async SignUpAsync(ctx: Context) {
    try {
        let code = await SignUpVerification.GenerateCode();
        let user = await this.InfoFromRequest(ctx.request.body);
        user.Code = code;
        await db.AddUser(user);
        console.log('added db user');
        //await SignUpVerification.SendVerificationText(user.PhoneNumber, code)
        console.log('success message');
        ctx.body = 'Success';
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.status = 400;
        ctx.body = err;
    }
};

private async InfoFromRequest(requestBody: any) {
    return {
        Email: requestBody['email'],
        FirstName: requestBody['firstname'],
        MiddleName: requestBody['middlename'],
        LastName: requestBody['lastname'],
        Pwd: requestBody['pwd'],
        PhoneNumber: requestBody['phonenumber']
    } as IUserModel;
}
```

**Call to the model**

```
async AddUser(newUser: IUserModel) {
    return await userModel.AddUser(newUser);
}
```

**Model call**

```
async AddUser(newUser: IUserModel) {
    try {
        var userToSave = new User({
            name: {
                firstname: newUser.FirstName,
                middlename: newUser.MiddleName,
                lastname: newUser.LastName
            },
            email: newUser.Email,
            pwd: newUser.Pwd,
            code: newUser.Code,
            phonenumber: newUser.PhoneNumber
        });

        let result = await userToSave.save();
        console.log('New User saved');
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

**Method generates code that is returned from Model Call**

```
static async GenerateCode() {
    return await (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000).toString();
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your `SignUpAsync` middleware should return a promise that Koa can await. Perhaps `return db.AddUser(user).then(`?

Comment: @Greg I tried what you said it still didn't await. I edit the code to better reflect what seems to be the way to do this.

Comment: @JoshuadeLeon not seeing anything really wrong with this. Can you share how you added the `SignUpAsync` middleware to the app?

Comment: Aside: use `crypto.randomBytes()` for secret codes!

Comment: Bonus2: GenerateCode does not need to be async, and neither does InfoFromRequest.

Comment: @Evert you were on to the right track with your first comment. The function when added to the router was not async and not awaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evert was onto the right track with looking at how the function was added in the middleware.

**Before**

```
this.router.post(
            'login/',
            (ctx) => {
                this.controller.LoginAsync(ctx);
            }
        );
```

**Correct**

```
this.router.post(
            'login/',
            async (ctx) => {
                await this.controller.LoginAsync(ctx);
            }
        );
```